# Get relevant topics by matching multiple topic by category using the Freebase API

Tags: freebase, mql

How can I get related topics given an mid?

Aka I have the mid: '/m/0mgcr', which is the offspring
and I want to get a list of related bands.

What's the best way to tackle this?

Another way to ask this would probably be:

If I have a band that has multiple genres how do I find all other bands that have the exact same genres as that band? not just one...

Comment: If you have the genre, just make sure you put the query in an array in order to have the API return a list of results. However, for the general problem of finding related entities, I don't think this is supported... you may want to load the RDF dumps, instead, and then use some custom processing in order to do that.

Comment: thanks thats what I was trying but I cant quite get the right syntax for that query! Do you know what it is?

Comment: What query have you tried?

Comment: {
  "type": "/music/artist",
  "name": [],
  "genre": [
    "Rock music",
    "Ska",
    "Reggae",
    "New Wave",
    "Post-punk",
    "Pop rock",
    "2 Tone",
    "Punk rock",
    "Reggae fusion",
    "Ska punk",
    "Jazz fusion",
    "Reggae rock"
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use the reverse edge to go from the genre to the artists in that genre. Example:

```
{
 "type": "/music/genre",
 "mid": "/m/07sbbz2",
 "artists": [{
   "mid": null,
   "name": null
 }]
}
```

This will give you the name and machine ID of the artists in the genre "/m/07sbbz2" (Rock and roll).